# Bootstrap, Select Option placeholder only showing after first submit

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a placeholder for my dropdown multiple options using Angular and Bootstrap. But looks like i'm doing it wrong. I made a option for a placeholder like `please select` and put it on top but it is not showing until i made a first submit.

```html
<label>Question</label><br>
<select #question="ngModel" name="question" [(ngModel)]="AppService.selectedquestion.question" class="empty form-control">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please select</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>  
  </select><br>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

I think it caused by my `ngModel` part.Can anyone help me figure this out, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the `hidden` attribute, you can see the *"Please select"* option even after 1st submit. Hope this meets your requirements

```html
<label>Question</label><br>
<select #question="ngModel" name="question" [(ngModel)]="AppService.selectedquestion.question" class="empty form-control">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Please select</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>  
  </select><br>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Submit</button>
```